# Can i disable windows updates while i am connecting to a specific hot-spot?

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, windows-update

When i work "on the go", I sometime connect my windows laptop to a hotspot created by my android phone.

Since my cellular data usage is limited, i want to disable windows updates (and actually any other high bandwidth background downloads) during this time.

Any idea how can I do it?

I am using windows 8.1

Comment: Sure;  Before you connect to the hotspot; change the setting.  8.1 also supports indicating your using a metered connection.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. Can you indicate where can i change the setting?

Comment: which one?  The Windows Update setting is in the same location its always been.  The metered connection indicator is when you connect through the General Charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution thanks to @Ramhound comments.

A connection can be set as a metered connection through the charms bar in windows 8.x

See also screenshots here
http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/configure-metered-connections-in-windows-8/